# Change SQL time format to HH31:MI:SS

Tags: sql, time, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, gtfs

I would like to insert a time value in the format of `HH31:MI:SS` instead of the typical `HH24:MI:SS`. This format is not mine, the GTFS allows hours over than 24.

For example,

```
insert into stop_times values((to_date('28:20:02", "HH31:MI:SS")), 
(to_date('31:02:25", "HH31:MI:SS)));
```

However, I am getting an error with message: `date format not recognized`.

Is it possible to change the default format (`HH24:MI:SS`) to `HH31:MI:SS`?

I use SQL Developer.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?  I'm not familiar with there being more than 24 hours in a day.

Comment: are you trying to show the elapsed time? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: @Siyual Haha, me too! Apparently, the output will be of the `HH31:MM:SS` format.

Comment: As far as I know no database supports GTFS times.  Your best bet would probably be to convert to seconds, store the number as an integer, then parse it back to hours, minutes and seconds when you extract it.  Not ideal, but blame Google for coming up with such a daft format.

Comment: @George Is that the answer that you are looking for? If so mark it as the answer. or let me know what else is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: Not sure what you expect your output to be: 
The amount of the time you have given `31:02:25` which becomes `111745` seconds. Now convert these seconds to the following:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(x/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(x,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(x,60),'FM00')
FROM DUAL
```

where `x` is the number of seconds

TO_CHAR should be able to handle 9999 hours!